# How to solve the problem of too many sequentially patterned columns in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table "projects", which contains several repeated columns, example: img1, img2, img3, there are many columns in this pattern, I thought of putting a specific separator in a single cell, such as " ; ", but I don't know if it is the best option. Should I do this breakpoint, do the multiple columns patterned in sequence, or is there something better to do?

I should do like this:

| img1 | img2 | img3 | img4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| asset/cover1.png | asset/cover2.png | asset/cover3.png | asset/cover4.png |
| asset/cover5.png | asset/cover6.png | asset/cover7.png | asset/cover8.png |

or like this:

| imgs1 | imgs2 |
| --- | --- |
| asset/cover1.png;asset/cover2.png;asset/cover3.png | asset/cover4.png;asset/cover5.png;asset/cover6.png |
| asset/cover7.png;asset/cover8.png;asset/cover9.png | asset/cover10.png;asset/cover11.png;asset/cover12.png |

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110402/sql-table-linking-is-it-better-to-have-a-linking-table-or-a-delimited-column). tl;dr it's usually better to use linking tables for many to many relationships

Comment: Neither is good, read up on relational normalisation.

Comment: Also, even though `;` is used as a possible separator instead of commas [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Why are you worrying about this? Many columns in a table might be ugly and/or suboptimal, but it isn't really a problem you have to solve.